# i can't nested add in elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, nested, postman, guzzle

i have a problem with elasticsearch
when i send request for add nested object with elasticseach script in postman it work but when i wanna send request for add new object in elasticseach , All objects in my index disappear.
it not work , this eliminates all other objects in elasticsearch and only add itself:

```
        $params = [
            'script' => [
                'source' => 'ctx._source.products.add(params.products)',
                'lang'=>'painless',
                'params' =>['id'=>1,'name'=>'john']
            ]

        ];

   $http = new Client();
        $result = $http->request('post','http://my_server/new_frotel/_update/123', [
            'body' =>$params,
            'headers'=>[
              'content-type'=>'application/json'
            ]
        ])
```

but it work in postman

```
POST : http://my_server/new_frotel/_update/123


{
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.products.add(params.products)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
            "products": {
                "id":1,
                "name":"john"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see you using `$params` anywhere after defining its content.

Comment: There was a problem typing it but it still didn't work

Comment: Ok, now you show you are passing `$params` into `body`... granted I've not used this class, so I'm not sure where it should go ;) but putting params into a body doesnt sound right to me.